# Stop console application from closing on key C#

Tags: c#, console-application

Hello I have a console application and every time the user types something and enters it closes it and I dont really want that in my application since it needs multiple inputs. I've tried debugging and opening the file itself.

Is there a answer?
-HoverNot

Comment: add `Console.ReadLine()` at the bottom of your program.

Comment: Please show a portion of your code. Based on the implemented logic we will to be able to help you better

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it's closing due to an unhandled exception. Show your code and give an example of an input that causes the problem. Of course, you would do yourself a huge favor if you stepped through the code in the debugger and saw how far it got.

Answer (score 2):

A console application closes when it runs out of code to execute

You can halt until someone has pressed enter by asking for input:

```
Console.ReadLine()
```

If you want to force the program to keep waiting for input, you can use

```
while(true) {
    Console.ReadLine()
}
```

Then the window won't close until you press ctrl-c or click the cross (or kill the process some other way)